# How to test the randomness of a sequence of real m-tuples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-generation, randomness

1) Let $\{a_i\}_{i = 1, ...,n}$ be a real sequence generated by a pseudorandom number generator. How can I check the randomness of such real numbers using, for instance, Runs test?

2) Assume three independent sequences of real numbers $\{a_i\}_{i = 1, ...,n}$, $\{b_i\}_{i = 1, ...,n}$ and $\{c_i\}_{i = 1, ...,n}$ are generated by the same PRNG using different seed keys. How can I infer the randomness of a sequence of *m*-tuples, for instance 3-tuples $\{(a_i,b_i,c_i)\}_{i = 1, ...,n}$?

3) How can I translate the randomness of each coordinate to the randomness of 3-tuples?